# SONAME incosistency of shared protobuf lib when building with autogen and cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, build, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

When I build shared protobuf (Version 3.15.8) libs with autogen I get *libprotoc.so.26*:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-shared
make
```

When I build it with cmake I get *libprotobuf.so.3.15.8.0*.

```
cd cmake && mkdir build && cd build
cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on ..
make
```

Is there a way to build *libprotoc.so.26* with cmake? (How can I set the SONAME there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking for the [`SOVERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html) property of the shared library target.  As far as I am aware, there is no command-line option to affect target properties, so you would need to modify the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt` file.  You'll need to identify the CMake target name chosen for the library (a characteristic of the project, not of CMake itself), say "protobuf_lib".  You would then add a command of the form

```
target_set_properties(protobuf_lib
    PROPERTIES SOVERSION 26)
```

Alternatively, if there is already a `target_set_properties` command for the target in question, you could add the `SOVERSION 26` to the property list in that command.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I patched  cmake/libprotobuf.cmake  `set_target_properties(libprotobuf PROPERTIES
-    VERSION ${protobuf_VERSION}
+    SOVERSION 26
     OUTPUT_NAME ${LIB_PREFIX}protobuf
     DEBUG_POSTFIX "${protobuf_DEBUG_POSTFIX}")`
And now it works as expected. (although it would be nice to not hardcode the 26)